# Register DbContext along with DbContextOptions Using Unity Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I want to register AppDbContext class for DbContext. This is how my class looks like:

```
 public class AppDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        // DbSets here
    }
```

This is how I used to register in **Startup.cs** file

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=db; trusted_connection=true;");
            });
```

I now have to register the same Context using **Unity Container** along with **DbContextOptions**.
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I got the same problem.